# Best test Android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, android-emulator

I have just started doing Android development. Unfortunately, I have found that AVD emulator in Eclipse is so slow that it's unworkable. I have tweaked settings with some improvement, but still it's too slow.

I have an ASUS tablet, which I test with, but I don't have an actual phone size device. Can you recommend an inexpensive phone size Android device that is representative of the hardware available? I don't want to put a phone contract on it.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My usual testers involve a couple of typical, one-year old (Android 2.3) handsets, which I've collected from friends who bought the "latest and greatest," as well as a G1 (worst-case scenario) and Motorola Charm (worst screen on any Android phone I've ever seen), to give reaslistic lower limits on what most people are carrying. Of course, those people who buy apps tend to be using much newer phones, but depending on your target, supporting 2- or 3-year-old handsets may be critically important...

Answer (score 2):

Android does have "developer" phones, called the Nexus series (Nexus 1, Nexus S, and most recently Galaxy Nexus).

However I find it necessary to point out that NO one device will represent the success of the app in the wild. Get ready for some troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy i9000.
It isn't too fast a device or one with a lot of memory like the newest phones, but it's generally good enough and I think represents the average hardware found on most people's phones. 
I find myself working quite a lot on performance in my apps, which is a good thing.
It's also relatively cheap.

Whatever you do, I don't suggest buying one of the latest phones such as the Galaxy S2, Galaxy Nexus etc, because they'll run everything fast, and other (most) people will probably experience lag on their less advanced phones.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to possibly get a G1 to see how backwards compatible your app is and slowly work your way up if money isn't to much of an issue.  Don't stick to your favorite phone company(Motorola, HTC, etc.) so you don't leave a large group with their new app as useful as a rock.  Also try a few different screen sizes to see how your app copes with multiple sizes(no stretching or warping). If you find a phone with a low price and run of the mill specs or worse that can run your app seamlessly your in pretty good shape.

Good Luck- Lijap